# Enabling list(instance) or tuple(instance) on instance of user-defined class

Tags: python

Is there a way to enable using the standard type constructors such as int, set, dict, list, tuple, etc. to coerce an instance of a user-defined class to one of those types in a user-defined way? For example

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=1
        self.b=2
```

and then having

```
>>> ex = Example()
>>> dict(ex)
{"a":1, "b":2}
```

I don't know if that's possible, and if it is, what I would need to add in the class definition. Right now I need this and I implement a "as_dict" method which I call on the object, but it doesn't look as natural.

Comment: Most built-in constructors take an iterable as an argument, so you can make your type iterable

Comment: I realized something important: There is a ExampleClass.__dict__ attribute to every class, but *do not* overwrite it. It contains all the attributes of the class and is called for other purposes than converting the class to a dictionary, by typing instance.__dict__...

Comment: Yes, `__dict__` is an attribute meant to hold the instances namespace dictionary. It is not a hook for the `dict` constructor, unlike `__int__`

Comment: Note, your `as_dict` solution is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: It does work and does what I want, but I like the idea of being able to apply 'dict' or 'list' on my object; it makes the code look more pythonic in my opinion. I usually write such things when defining constructors via class methods such as "Config.from_json" or "SomeObjectLoader.from_config" (as an example...).. but if I want to build a primitive type like dict or list, it's nicer to have a pythonic construction, I guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make your type iterable by adding an `__iter__()` method. Trivially:

```
class Example:

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2

    def __iter__(self):
        yield "a", self.a
        yield "b", self.b
```

This yields a sequence of tuples containing name/value pairs, which `dict()` is happy to consume.

```
dict(Example())    # {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Of course, there's a lot of repeating yourself in there.  So you could instead write `__iter__()` to work with a predefined list of attributes:

```
def __iter__(self):
    names = "a", "b"
    for name in names:
        yield name, getattr(self, name)
```

You could also have it introspect *all* the attributes from the instance, omitting attributes whose values are callable:

```
def __iter__(self):
    names = dir(self)
    for name in names:
        value = getattr(self, name)
        if not callable(value):
             yield name, value
```

Or have it yield from the instance's `__dict__` attribute, which contains only the attributes stored directly on the instance (the `dir()` method above also finds inherited attributes):

```
def __iter__(self):
    yield from self.__dict__.items()
```

Comment: That works for dict and list because they're sort of special types among the others, but what about if I want to convert it to an int or float? (I understand that the use case might not be so clear in those cases, and to be honest I am satisfied with your answer, but I'm just curious to know if that is possible.)

I'm already capable with iterators and iterables, I just thought that this would require calling dict(iter(Example())) instead of dict(Example()). That's a nice one!

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva "That works for dict and list because they're sort of special types among the others" Not really. They are both *containers*, but most built-in types are containers. For the numeric types, there are built-in hooks, `__int__`, `__float__` and `__complex__`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make your object [`iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types).

Both `list` and `tuple` accept an iterable as their argument, which they will repeatedly consume until to construct the new collection. To enable your class to work with this mechanism, you will need to define at least the [`__iter__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__) method, and possibly also the [`__next__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__) method, depending on the specific semantics of your class.

Your implementation of `__iter__` will need to return an object that implentents the [iterator protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types). If you internally use an iterable collection, this can be as simple as returning that collection.

In your case, it seems you want your object to behavior like an iterable collection of tuples. A possible implementation for the behavior you're looking for would be

```
class Example: 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.a=1 
        self.b=2 

    def __iter__(self): 
        for elem in ('a', 'b'): 
            yield (elem, getattr(self, elem))                                                                                                                

>>> dict(Example())                                                                                               
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Here, we make use of a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) to produce an iterable that will yield the tuples `('a', self.a)` and `('b', self.b)` in turn.

Comment: You almost certainly do **not** want to define `__next__` because that wouldake your object an *iterator* not merely iterable

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You're right, it depends on the semantics of the class your are defining. You will either define just `__iter__` for an iterable, or both `__iter__` and `__next__` for an iterator. I brought up both in my response as a teaching point so that the OP may become aware of the two protocols, allowing them to select whichever is more appropriate for their application.

Comment: @Brian: I was already aware of the iterator and iterable protocols, I just didn't know that list and dict accepted iterables, I thought it only accepted iterators (which would mean I would have to call dict(iter(Example())) instead of dict(Example()). Thanks for your answer, very enlightening!

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva no, that is not what that means. Even if they only did accept iterators (a strange requirement), you *wouldn't* have to call `iter(some_iterator)` before passing it to `list` or `dict` or any of the other container constructors, because `iter(some_iterator)` always returns **the iterator itself**, i.e. `iter(some_iterator) is iterator`